# stacked bar plot in R gives error

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to process a survey, I have Q1A to Q1H with answers of Q1 which I want to compare in a stacked barplot in R. All of them contain integer data (categorical).

When I run:

```
counts <- table(Q1A, Q1B, Q1C, Q1D, Q1E, Q1F, Q1G)
barplot(counts, main="Motivations for research",
xlab="motivation",
col=c('blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange', 'purple', 'yellow', 'grey'),
legend = rownames(counts))
```

I get:

```
 Error in.... 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

What am I doing wrong? is this easier to do with ggplot2?

/edit:

output of dput for Q1A and Q1B is [here](http://pastebin.com/yJKY9Hcc).

Comment: Please edit your question to give us the output of `dput(Q1A)`, `dput(Q1B)` and so forth.

Comment: The first argument of `barplot` expects a vector or matrix. You are providing it with a `table` object, which is an array.

Comment: Stephan: I have edited and added the dputs. 
Roland: I think you are right but I was just following a tutorial and this is how they did it..

Comment: Thanks. Your `counts` is a 7-dimensional array, not a matrix. You won't be able to visualize that using a barplot. You *can* use a stacked barplot to visualize a 2x2 contingency matrix, e.g., for your first two variables: `barplot(table(Q1A,Q1B))` I don't find it very enlightening, though. Check out @maloneypatr's reply.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what your bar plot is supposed to look like, so I have a couple examples for you.  I'm also using the `ggplot2`, `plyr`, & `combine` packages

```
library(gdata)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

q <- combine(q1a, q1b)
qSum <- count(q)

ggplot(qSum, aes(x = data, y = freq, fill = `source`)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

ggplot(qSum, aes(x = data, y = freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_grid(`source` ~ .)
```

Comment: Thanks - it seems to work great, I get a few warning messages about missing values and also this one: Error in layout_base(data, rows, drop = drop) :  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting. any ideas? cheers

Comment: For facetting, "source" has to be put in backwards apostrophes since it is a special function.  The backwards apostrophe is next to the 1 button.  You press shift to get the tilde, but don't press shift.  This should solve the problem?